# abrir Puerto serial con ExtSerialPort en Qt5

Tags: qt

Buenas Tardes / Días
Estoy desarrollando una app con Qt5 en la cual requiero abrir y leer un puerto serial, pero este no abre estoy en Ubuntu 14.04

```
    //QextSerialPort *Puerto = new QextSerialPort(); //Intenté de esta forma y la siguiente
Puerto = new QextSerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0");  // En mi header tengo declarado a puerto como QextSerialPort *Puerto
Puerto->setQueryMode(QextSerialPort::Polling);
Puerto->setPortName("/dev/ttyUSB0");
Puerto->setBaudRate(BAUD19200);
Puerto->setDataBits(DATA_8);
Puerto->setStopBits(STOP_1);
Puerto->setParity(PAR_NONE);
Puerto->setFlowControl(FLOW_OFF);
if(Puerto->open(QextSerialPort::ReadOnly)){ // Ya intenté con ReadWrite y WriteOnly
    qDebug() << "Puerto abierto";
    Puerto->close();
}else{
    qDebug() << "No se puede abrir el puerto";
}
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te falta añadir los targets en tu archivo .pro:

```
QT       -= gui

TARGET = qextserialport_sencill_transmisio
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle  # MacOS no es el objetivo

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

# AÃ±adidos mios al proyecto creado por defecto.
# Como son dependientes de la plataforma destino, utilizamos
# opciones distintas según la plataforma objetivo

win32 {
    # anyadir las librerias de qext...
    LIBS += -LS:/dsii/dsii_qt/qextserialport/build
    LIBS += -lqextserialportd1

    # anaydir donde localizar los archivos de cabecera de qext...
    INCLUDEPATH += S:/dsii/dsii_qt/qextserialport

    # etiquetas para C que permite saber que tipo de implementación serie es
    DEFINES  = _TTY_WIN_
}

unix {
    # anyadir las librerias de qext...
    LIBS += -L/home/aperles/tmp/qextserialport/build
    LIBS += -lqextserialportd

    # anaydir donde localizar los archivos de cabecera de qext...
    INCLUDEPATH += /home/aperles/tmp/qextserialport

    # etiquetas para saber en que tipo de sistema estamos
    DEFINES   = _TTY_POSIX_

}
```

Comment: Hola abrahams.
Ya agregué las lineas del target y las de unix que son las que usaría por el momento, pero aun así no abre el puerto, creo que la forma en la que agregé las lineas no es la correcta 
`unix {
    LIBS += -L/home/aperles/tmp/qextserialport/build
    LIBS += -lqextserialportd
    INCLUDEPATH += /home/aperles/tmp/qextserialport
    DEFINES   = _TTY_POSIX_
}` 
las agregué tal cual pero supongo que se agrega la ruta segun mi pc pero no se que archivos se intentan llamar ya los busqué y no los encuentro.

Comment: si solo vas a usar lo de unix quita las llaves `unix {` y su cierre `}` y solo deja lo de adentro mas lo que ya traía tu archivo .pro

Comment: Ya inserte el código pero me salta error no puede encontrar -lqextserialportd

Comment: Entonces es posible que no este instalada o este en otra ruta. Revisa estas urls: https://qextserialport.github.io/  y esta otra http://www.disca.upv.es/aperles/qt/port_serie_Qt/port_serie_Qt.html

Comment: Ya logré abrirlo, tenías razón con la instalación la tenía en otro lugar pero aun así no me dejaba hasta que cambie los permisos de ubuntu para que me dejara acceder a los puertos, puse mi perfil en el grupo dialout con el siguiente comando: 
"sudo adduser usuario dialout"
Gracias abrahamhs!